# React rendering html elements in nested loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data structure like this {key: [array of object]}. I want to render each element in array of object using nested for loop like this:

```
for each entry(k, v) in map:
    for each element in array v:
        display html data
```

I am using react version 16.

I tried this in JSX:

```
class Positions extends React.Component {
    renderPosition(position) {
        var expiry = position["ExpiryDay"] + "-" + position["ExpiryMonth"] + "-" + position["ExpiryYear"];
        console.log(expiry);
        return (<label>{expiry}</label>);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.positionsGrouped.forEach(function(positions) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            {positions.map(function(position) {
                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        {this.renderPosition(position)}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            }.bind(this))}
                        </div>
                    );
                }.bind(this))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the JS that it compiles to:

```
class Positions extends React.Component {
    renderPosition(position) {
        var expiry = position["ExpiryDay"] + "-" + position["ExpiryMonth"] + "-" + position["ExpiryYear"];
        console.log(expiry);
        return React.createElement(
            "label",
            null,
            expiry
        );
    }
    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            this.props.positionsGrouped.forEach(function (positions) {
                return React.createElement(
                    "div",
                    null,
                    positions.map(function (position) {
                        return React.createElement(
                            "div",
                            null,
                            this.renderPosition(position)
                        );
                    }.bind(this))
                );
            }.bind(this))
        );
    }
}
```

However I don't see anything being rendered except for the top most div. Here is the rendered html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is what I see in react developer tools:

```
<App>
    <Positions>
        <div></div>
    </Positions>
</App>
```

I don't see any errors in the console. I expected at least three nested divs to be rendered however I only see one so it sounds like something is wrong at the level of the first for loop. But, I do see my expiry variable being printed to console properly so I know renderPosition is getting called with the correct data.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I'm new to react and sorry for any typos. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.props.positionsGrouped.forEach` would return undefined. I mean it wouldn't return anything. So nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Instead of writing it as an answer you should written it in the comment of that respective answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your component code like this

```
import React from "react";
class Positions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderPosition = this.renderPosition.bind(this);
  }
  renderPosition(position) {
    var expiry = position["name"] + "-" + position["title"];
    console.log(expiry);
    return <label>{expiry}</label>;
  }
  render() {
    const { positionsGrouped } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {positionsGrouped.map(positions => {
          const keys = Object.keys(positions);
          return (
            <div>
              {positions[keys[0]].map(position => {
                return <div>{this.renderPosition(position)}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Positions;
```

Inside your parent file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Position from "./test";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  var positionGroup = [
    {
      a: [
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        },
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        },
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      b: [
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        },
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        },
        {
          name: "hello",
          title: "sdfd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Position positionsGrouped={positionGroup} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `forEach` is `undefined` no matter what you return in callback function. use `map` instead.

```
class Positions extends React.Component {
  getExpiry(position) {
    return `${position.ExpiryDay}-${position.ExpiryMonth}-${position.ExpiryYear}`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.positionsGrouped.map(positions => (
          <div>
            {positions.map((position) => (
              <div>
                <label>{this.getExpiry(position)}</label>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I changed your code a little to make it more concise.